# Google (PageSpeed) search result system changing from 1 July 2018

Tags: wordpress

Two months ago, I got to know that Google is changing its criteria for results, it will order those website first that have optimised their website for mobile as well.

I am trying to reduce my website's. 
Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

Guys how so you optimise your website, what technique should I use to reduce server response time and page rendering.

Sharing your views will be quite helpful for all of us. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for it.
Use [Autoptimize Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/)

In settings select Optimize JavaScript Code. That can solve many issues related to page rendering.